# Proving that $\min_{v\in S}(k\cdot f(v))=k\cdot \min_{v\in S}(f(v))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, riemann-sum

in my textbook, while the author trying to prove that if $f$ is an integrable function on a subrectangle $S$ which is a part of a region in $\mathbb R^2$ let's call it $R$, Then we have $$\int_Rk\cdot f=k\int_Rf, \text{ where } k\in \mathbb R$$

he said that $$\min_{v\in S}(k\cdot f(v))=k\cdot \min_{v\in S}(f(v))$$
but how can I prove this, the author didn't proved it, is it obvious?

Comment: It’s only true if $k\geq 0.$

Comment: And it easily  follows from $$a\leq b\implies ka\leq kb$$ when $k\geq 0.$

Comment: The author said $k$ is a number @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Then the author is wrong. @yassir It is easy to construct counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true unless $k\geq 0.$

For example, if $f(x,y)=\sin^2 x\sin^2 y$ on $S=[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi],$ and $k=-1$ then $$-1=\min_{v\in S} kf(v)\neq k\min_{v\in S}f(v)=k\cdot 0=0.$$

When $k<0$ you have:

$$\min_{v\in S} k\cdot f(v) = k\cdot \max_{v\in S} f(v)$$

**Proof** for $k\geq 0:$

If $k\geq 0$ and $v_0\in S$ such that $f(v_0)=\min_{v\in S}f(v),$ which is equivalent to  $$\forall v\in S, f(v_0)\leq f(v)$$ which implies that  $$\forall v\in S, k\cdot f(v_0)\leq k\cdot f(v).$$

Comment: but now how can you prove that $kf$ is also integrable, using the above property

Comment: That depends on your definition of integrable, which depends on the book somewhat. @Yassir If that was part of your question, it should have been in the question.

Comment: You should put $S$, instead of $V$ in your last inequality. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Thanks, fixed. @Yassir